# Single quote in hibernate query named parameter gives error

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to have a single quotation around the timeBucket. I have the following native sql, which is working perfectly fine.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT time_bucket('" + timeBucket + "', time) as timestamp, avg(cast(value as double precision)) as value" +
            " FROM agent_data " +
            " WHERE agent_id = :agentId and topic_id = :topicId" +
            " GROUP BY timestamp " +
            " ORDER BY timestamp DESC " +
            " LIMIT :noOfRecords", "GetAgentDataMapping")
            .setParameter("noOfRecords", noOfRecords)
            .setParameter("agentId", agentId)
            .setParameter("topicId", topicId)
            .getResultList();
```

I am concatenating timeBukcket parameter because if I use setParameter method to bind that variable, then I get error

```
"Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"
```

I tried using sql string concatenation like following. But it fails with same error:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT time_bucket('|| :timeBucket ||', time) as timestamp, avg(cast(value as double precision)) as value" +
            " FROM agent_data " +
            " WHERE agent_id = :agentId and topic_id = :topicId" +
            " GROUP BY timestamp " +
            " ORDER BY timestamp DESC " +
            " LIMIT :noOfRecords", "GetAgentDataMapping")
            .setParameter("timeBucket", timeBucket)
            .setParameter("noOfRecords", noOfRecords)
            .setParameter("agentId", agentId)
            .setParameter("topicId", topicId)
            .getResultList();
```

Also I used `SELECT time_bucket('''|| :timeBucket ||''', time)` to escape single quote.

But same error, no use. This is really frustrating that Hibernate doesn't have a quick solution for such simple thing. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it work if you'd use positional parameters?

Comment: @Davide No, it doesn't. How come Hibernate doesn't have a solution for this?

Comment: I think there is an error in your code, but first try what I suggested below. Apart from that, you could just use HQL for this. Is there any reason to use SQL?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I just don't like to use HQL as in future this query will become complex and HQL may not be the ideal solution

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what it is that you think HQL is not the ideal solution for?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using timescale? What is the issue with using the following?

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT time_bucket(:timeBucket, time) as timestamp, avg(cast(value as double precision)) as value" +
        " FROM agent_data " +
        " WHERE agent_id = :agentId and topic_id = :topicId" +
        " GROUP BY timestamp " +
        " ORDER BY timestamp DESC " +
        " LIMIT :noOfRecords", "GetAgentDataMapping")
        .setParameter("timeBucket", timeBucket)
        .setParameter("noOfRecords", noOfRecords)
        .setParameter("agentId", agentId)
        .setParameter("topicId", topicId)
        .getResultList();
```

AFAIU the parameter to `time_bucket` needs to be a string or interval. Maybe you need to cast the parameter to an interval `cast(:timeBucket as interval)`

Comment: If I use cast(:timeBucket as interval) then it works. Thanks for the suggestion. Otherwise the issue is same as I posted originally

Comment: Not sure what you tried, but the examples you posted look like you used it in a wrong way. `'|| :timeBucket ||'` is a string literal within which there is obviously no parameter replacement going on. What you probably wanted to do is `'' || :timeBucket || ''`